# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried all everything but I couldnt solve the problem and I will be very appreciated if you could help me to solve this problem. Also, I am new in this and learn it with different approaches.

I resize my MNIST images into the [22, 22] and then reshape them to the [1,484]. Finally I want to feed my network model but I get an error:
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'

My code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
tf.reset_default_graph()
from numpy import array

mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 484])

W = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=[484, 10],
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

b = tf.get_variable("bias", shape=[10],
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), 
reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)

batch_size=50

for _ in range(10000):
        batch_img, batch_label = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)  

        imgs = batch_img.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
        print(imgs.shape[0])

        resized_imgs = np.zeros((imgs.shape[0], 22, 22, 1))
        for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
            resized_imgs[i, ..., 0] = transform.resize(imgs[i, ..., 0], 
        (22,22))
        image = array(resized_imgs).reshape(imgs.shape[0], 484)
        print(image.shape)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: image, y_: batch_label})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: 
mnist.test.labels}))
print ("done with training")
```

Very appreciated for the help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **OneHot** labels to `(50, 10)` shape to match the shape, Example:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/Users/xiachen/IdeaProjects/scala99/model/tensorflow', one_hot=True)
```

also you need to care about your session scope for your **prediction**,

and you should initialize variables before training `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful. It works fine now. In my case, I used

    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

Why did we use one_hote=True? I will be appreciated if you can explain it to me.

Comment: @Esriak [One Hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot), if you still are confusion, try to ask another question, so some guys also will help you to figure out.